# jQuery remove 5 specific divs base on the text inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to delete 5 divs base on the text inside the class name.
Here is my div

```
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>Adam</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>Adam</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>Adam</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>Adam</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>

<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>Adam</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>Adam</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>Adam</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>Adam</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>Adam</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
<div class='instagram'>
  <div class='name'>John</div>
</div>
```

So as you can see inside the `.instagram` div, there's a `class='name'`. I want to delete the last 5 divs of John and Adam.

How can I do that?

I already know how to remove the last 5 divs.

```
jQuery('body').find(".instagram:nth-last-child(-n+5)").remove();
```

But removing the last 5 divs per name is difficult for me, your help will be greatly appreciated.

***Please note that these names are dynamic(John and Steve). These names came from an ajax result. :)***

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) with [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
jQuery('body').find(".name").filter(':contains(John), :contains(Adam)').parent().slice(-5).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gu9yuedt/)

Comment: Is this possible if those names are dynamic? The John and Adam are just example names.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower concantate the string and insert the name variable `':contains('+data.name+')`

Comment: Doesn't it simply remove 5 last items? Seems like that in your test

Comment: @spliter it removes the last 5 items with the name content as `John` or `Adam`

Comment: @ArunPJohny but you don't remove 5 Adams and 5 Johns. Remove your JS and see where the 5th last John is for example. Then re-enable JS and see that your JS removess only 3 "Johns", located after your indicator becausey ou have exactly 5 Adam+John items after it.

Comment: Maybe we confuse the task – you are really grouping Johns and Adams and remove 5 last items of them. My solution proposes removing 5 last Johns and 5 last Adams without grouping ;)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Would this remove the .instagram div or just remove the .name inside the .instagram div? I think that is what it does. What i want is to remove the whole .instagram div. :)

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower yes it removes the `instagram` element

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for your answer, actually this is the site i'm working on http://www.mtgmusic.no/ It is still not working on my end because there is a div below the name, in this site, the names are rayleeofficial , erikogkriss ,etc..so when I use your code, it does not delete the entire div. Any ideas please? :)

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower replace `.parent().slice(-5).remove()` with `.slice(-5).closest('.instagram').remove()`

Answer (score 0):

@PinoyStackOverflower if what you really need is to remove 5 last Adamas and 5 last Johns, I would go for simple

```
$('.name:contains("Adam")').slice( -5 ).parent().remove(),
$('.name:contains("John")').slice( -5 ).parent().remove();
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pk4qnkae/1/)

Comment: I think this would only remove the .name class. This would not remove the .instagram div. I want to remove the .instagram div as well where the name lies. :)

Comment: No, @PinoyStackOverflower, it does remove  ``.instagram`` as well. Check the source of the result window, please ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually this is the site i'm working on http://www.mtgmusic.no/ It is still not working on my end because there is a div below the name, in this site, the names are rayleeofficial , erikogkriss ,etc..so when I use your code, it does not delete the entire div. Any ideas please? :)